# How to update outerscope variable from the onSuccess() method of anonymous class Firebase.ValueResultHandler

Tags: android, firebase

I am calling this class' method from other class and i always gets `false`, How can I update the outer scope data member (status) in

> onSuccess()

method, whenever I call this method it always return null, can anyone tell me how can I get the correct result

```
public class UserAccount {

Firebase firebase;

private UserAccount() {
firebase = new Firebase(firebase_url);
}

public static UserAccount getUserAccountInstance(){
    return userAccountInstance;
}



boolean status = false; 


   public boolean createUserAccount(String username, String password)throws FirebaseException{

    if(firebase == null)
        firebase = new Firebase(firebase_url);
    firebase.createUser(username+"@firebase.com", password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
            System.out.println("Successfully created user account with uid:" + result.get("uid"));
            UserAccount.this.status=true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong!! \n Account cannot be created.. useraccount");
            throw new FirebaseException(firebaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });

    System.out.println("user"+status);// this produces false

    return status;

}
```

I also try static keyword but it didnot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is a cloud-hosted service. To create a user (in this case), the app needs to make a call to the server, which will spend some time and only then will your user have been created. To prevent blocking the application (which would leave to the infamous [Application Not Responding dialog](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)), the Firebase client performs the operation in the background and lets the main thread of your app continue. That's why you'll immediately see the output of `System.out.println("user"+status)`.

You're likely calling this function with something like:

```
var isCreated = createUserAccount("Abdul Malik", "correcthorsebatterystaple");
if (isCreated) {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The user was created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to create user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This cannot work, since you cannot block the main thread without creating a horrible user experience. The solution is to invert your logic. Instead of saying "first create a user, then do xyz", rephrase it to "create a user, when that is done do xyz".

You do this by moving the xyz code *into* the `createUserAccount` method:

```
public boolean createUserAccount(String username, String password)throws FirebaseException{

    if(firebase == null)
        firebase = new Firebase(firebase_url);
    firebase.createUser(username+"@firebase.com", password, new Firebase.ValueResultHandler<Map<String, Object>>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Map<String, Object> result) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The user was created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            UserAccount.this.status=true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed to create user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            throw new FirebaseException(firebaseError.getMessage());

        }
    });
    createUserAccount("Abdul Malik", "correcthorsebatterystaple");
```

See also my answer here: [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)

Comment: I knew that method is returning value before it can execute 'onSuccess()' method, but i did not know how to wait for the onSuccess method to execute in the createuseraccount() , so that it returns the new value, thank you for telling the solution

Answer (score 0):

Just use a regular POJO. Here is an example.

1) Create POJO:

```
class AnyPojo {

    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

2) Initiate and pass the AnyPojo instance to your method

```
    AnyPojo mPojo= new AnyPojo();

    AnyPojo returnMyMethod = MyMethod (mPojo);
    returnMyMethod.getStatus(); // <--- This must return "Anything you like"

    public AnyPojo MyMethod(final mPojo) {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
           mPojo.setStatus("Anything you like");
        }

        return mPojo;
    }
```